# Ruby list all files within a UNC path via WinRM

Tags: ruby, windows

I am attempting to execute a ruby script via WinRM

```
ruby "R:\Scripts\testDir.rb"
```

that contains the following code:

```
Dir.foreach("\\\\FileServer\\TestDir\\") { |x| 
    puts "Found #{x}" 
}
```

I have no problems executing the script locally on the server, but it fails with the following *Permission Denied* error via WinRM:

```
ruby : R:/Scripts/testDir.rb:1:in `open': Permission denied @ dir_initialize - \\FileServer\TestDir\ (Errno::EACCES)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (R:/Scripts...(Errno::EACCES):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    from R:/Scripts/testDir.rb:1:in `foreach'
    from R:/Scripts/testDir.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

When running the script locally, I get the following output.

```
Found .
Found ..
Found test.txt
Found test.tar.xz
```

My guess is that my script is failing because of the . and .. returned values being passed through WinRM, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Are you using a non-admin account to execute the script remotely? I.e. what is the account you are using for WinRM authentication? It is likely that it doesn't have sufficient permissions for either accessing the file path, or that it's not configured for WinRM. Can you run a simple "puts" script remotely via WinRM using the same account? Also, how exactly are you making the WinRM call?

Comment: I am able to run the same script locally with the same account. I am also able to access the file path and read, write, delete files within the directories.

Comment: Can you run a simple "puts" script remotely using the same account? Did you configure the account (in case it's not the default account) correctly, i.e. put it into the WinRM group, set the WMI namepsace permissions ...? Can you run a PowerShell test-wsman to the host in question sucessfully?

Comment: When running a simple puts "testing output" script, the output is fine. When running the testDir script locally, I get the following output:
Found .
Found ..
Found Test.txt
Found Test.tar.xz
I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was caused by [double-hopping](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/). The command I was running to execute the ruby script was from my local machine via WinRm.